# How to make a top down shooter?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, shooter

I want to know is with XNA 4.0 (and C#) How do I exactly make a top down shooter? I have been looking for ages, but have been unable to find out how.

If someone could tell me how to get started with it or possibly link me to a good easy to understand tutorial that would be fantastic!

Comment: The [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) explicitly says "how to make (or start making) a particular type of game" questions [are off topic](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-to-make-an-entire-game-x-off-topic).

Comment: Sorry about that :/, it won't happen again

Comment: @DarkMiner You can ask the question in chat when you get the required rep.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples on the XNA creators club on how to get started with making games. In fact I remember them giving you [the link](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/starterkits/) while you are downloading XNA to the samples: rendering this question quite lazy indeed.

The [XNA community project on CodePlex](http://xnacommunity.codeplex.com/) also has a slew of examples.